# Не срабатывает fputs

Tags: c++, c, файлы, filestream

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char tmpstr[255];
    FILE *stream;

    stream = fopen("ase.txt", "r+");

    fgets (tmpstr, 255, stream);
/*  fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_CUR);     */
    fputs("spice", stream);             // fprintf(stream, "%s","spice");  

    fclose(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

Почему-то не происходит запись в файл, однако, если раскомментировать строчку fseek - запись происходит. Аналогичная ситуация, если использовать fprintf вместо fputs.
Почему так происходит?

Comment: опечатка        ......................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно стандарту С (7.21.5.3 The fopen function)

> 7 When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third
>   character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and
>   output may be performed on the associated stream. However, **output
>   shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to
>   the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos,
>   or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without
>   an intervening call to a file positioning function,** unless the input
>   operation encounters endof-file. Opening (or creating) a text file
>   with update mode may instead open (or create) a binary stream in some
>   implementations.

Таким образом, вы не можете выполнять операцию записи в файл сразу же после операции чтения файла без промежуточного вызова  одной из функций: `fflush`, `fseek`, `fsetpos`, или `rewind`

Comment: @neko69, меня тоже всегда удивляло, *почему* FILE \* был так реализован (ведь по идее  ничто (кроме лени?) не мешает спрятать вызов fseek при смене режима файла внутрь). Впрочем, сейчас в Linux libio это (не взирая на стандарт С) исправлено и данная программа отработает без ошибки.